# How do you start multiple nodes of riak on the same machine?

Tags: erlang, riak

Trying to follow:
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/

I make multiple directories, dev1, dev2, dev3
After I start riak one time it gives me this error the second time

```
sudo /usr/sbin/riak start 
Node is already running!
```

How do I run multiple nodes from the same machine? It's only for learning purposes at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you must start riak which is in devN directories.  Kind of

```
dev1/bin/riak start
dev2/bin/riak start
```

etc ets.

the point is -- riak gets settings from vm.args file. To start multiple instances of riak on the same computer you need to have multiple instances of vm.args files. Several dev directories helps you to keep as many vm.args files (and data directories) as you want

Comment: Do you know how to make riak start with a specified vm.args? Running /usr/sbin/riak in a directory with vm.args gives the same error. I guess you need app.config too. I changed the node name and the ports but it still gives same error.

Comment: when you make riak by 'make devrel', it creates several 'dev' directories with full environment. Including vm.args, app.config, data and log dirs. And including 'bin/riak' start script that takes appropriate vm.args and app.config.

Comment: Yes, but what if you haven't built riak from source?